# Is there a way to find out which program is segfault-ing?

Tags: linux, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have a Busybox/Linux system where a mystery program is segfaulting rarely. Is there a way to find which program is doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the segmentation fault produces a "core" file, you can run `file <core-filename>` to identify the executable. You can also use `ddd` or `gdb` to debug the core file for more information.

Comment: I'm not getting core dumps, but I found [an article on enabling them](http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/archives/enabling-core-dumps-in-embedded-systems/ "Enabling Core Dumps in Embedded Systems")

Answer (score 5):

Uh, how do you know about the segfault anyway?

There is a [kernel log message](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L689) at priority info. It shows the [executable name](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/include/linux/sched.h#L1334) [without the directory part](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/exec.c#L1054). On some architectures, the [`debug.exception-trace` sysctl](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/kernel/sysctl.c#L1605) [must be set](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/mm/fault.c). Some architectures require a compile-time option and kernel command line parameter (e.g. [`CONFIG_USER_DEBUG`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/arm/mm/fault.c#L155) and [`user_debug`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c#L43) on arm).

Comment: On how I knew about the segfault: the console irregularly spat out "Segmentation Fault" with no further information.